# PostgreSQL - Delete last item of JSONB array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a field that holds JSONB arrays. How can I delete the last item?

```
[
  {
    "name": "test1",
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_column - (-1)`. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE).

---

```
WITH data(j) AS (
    VALUES ('[
      {
        "name": "test1"
      },
      {
        "name": "test2"
      },
      {
        "name": "test3"
      }
    ]'::JSONB)
)
SELECT j, j - (-1) AS all_but_last, j - 1 AS without_second_element
FROM data;
```

| j | all_but_last | without_second_element |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test3"}] | [{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}] | [{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test3"}] |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)